# jQuery - Check if some clicked on a special area/text in a textfield

Tags: jquery, parsing, click, textarea

Is it possible to check if some clicked in a textarea on a special area/text?

For example

```
<textarea>
  Tanken
  17/01/1970 13:31
  KT.: Bargeld
  BN.: 00000020
</textarea>
```

I want to start a `function()` if someone click on the date. The problem is that i can't use the position with numbers. The content from the Textarea is not static.

for example

```
<textarea>
  Time: 13:31
  KT.: Bargeld
  BN.: 00000020
  17/01/1970 
</textarea>
```

or

```
<textarea>
  Time: 13:31  / BN.: 00000020 / 17/01/1970 
</textarea>
```

The only thing that is static ist the date-format.

Any ideas? Or not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try getting the `selectionStart` of the `textarea`, from that deriving the word (wrapped between a pair of spaces). The last step is testing that word against some date pattern using regex, if it looks like a date, just run your code:

**HTML**:

```
<textarea>
   Time: 13:31
   KT.: Bargeld
   BN.: 00000020
   17/01/1970 
   Tanken
   17/01/1970 13:31
   KT.: Bargeld
   BN.: 00000020
   Tanken
   17/01/1970 13:31
   KT.: Bargeld
   BN.: 00000020
   Tanken
   17/01/1970 13:31
   KT.: Bargeld
   BN.: 00000020
</textarea>
```

**JS**:

```
$('textarea').click(function(e){
  var i = this.selectionStart;
  var k = i, j = i;
  var text = this.value;
  while(text[k] !=  ' ' && text[k] != '\n' &&k > 0) k--;
  while(text[j] != ' '&& text[j] != '\n' && j < text.length) j++;
  var clickedWord = text.substring(k,j).trim();
  //test if the clickedWord looks like a date, run some relevant code
  if(/^\d{0,2}([-\/])\d{0,2}\1\d{2,4}$/.test(clickedWord)){
    //your code here
    alert("Possible date clicked: " + clickedWord);
  }
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6UR5W/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if you can do it by simple `click` *(maybe it's possible but I think it  will be tricky or not "clean" at all)*. Try this workaround using `doubleclick` event:

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/W762t/

---

***CSS:***

Change cursor to let know users that `textarea` is clickable.

```
textarea {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

***HTML:***

I just added a `div` element for testing purposes.

```
<textarea>
Tanken
17/01/1970 13:31
KT.: Bargeld
BN.: 00000020
</textarea>
<textarea>
Time: 13:31  / BN.: 00000020 / 17/01/1970 
</textarea>
<div id="log"></div>
```

***jQuery:***

*Code Explanation:* When user `doubleclicks` on text and it matches the extracted `date` by `regex`, then it means that `doubleclick` event was done over the `date` text. So, `doubleclick` event  will help you to fit your requirement because It'll allow to grab the selected text.

***e.g:***

[image]

```
$(function() {

    var txt = $('textarea');

    txt.dblclick(function() {
        // Check for simple date format 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        var match = this.value.match(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/);
        // If there is a match, date exists
        var date = match ? match[0] : '';
        // If date exists
        if(date) {
            // Get selection object
            var selection = window.getSelection() || 
                            document.getSelection() || 
                            document.selection.createRange();
            // Get selected text
            var word = $.trim(selection.toString());
            // Check if selected text matches date string
            if(word && date.indexOf(word) > -1) {
                // Do an action, in this case, print a log
                showLog();
            }
        }        
    });

});

function showLog() {
    $('#log').append('[DoubleClick] was done over date text<br>');
};
```